# MeshRefinementFunction on 2D surfaces embedded in 3D

Tags: regions, mesh, discretization

DiscretizeRegion doesn't seem to run the supplied MeshRefinementFunction when meshing a 2D surface in 3D.

For example:

```
reg = MeshRegion[{{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}},
       Polygon[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}]];
DiscretizeRegion[reg, MeshRefinementFunction ->
       Function[{vertices, area}, area > 0.025 (1 - 10 Norm[Mean[vertices]])]]
```

Not only is their no difference between the output of `DiscretizeRegion` and `reg`, but it doesn't seem that is ever evaluated; when I put a `Print` in the `MeshRefinementFunction` I don't see any output.

This also fails with simpler regions eg `reg = Triangle[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}]`.

I wonder if this has to do with `MeshRefinementFunction` trying to use volume as the cell measure, and, as these regions have no volume, it fails in an unexpected way.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment rather than an answer.

[`DiscretizeRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html) understands how to mesh 2D objects embedded in 3D to some degree as can be shown by the following:

```
reg = MeshRegion[{{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}, 
   Polygon[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}]];
HighlightMesh[DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> #}], 
   1] & /@ {0.025, 0.0025}
```

[image: Max cell measure]

We can now show that your current mesh refinement function probably needs revision since it will cause an infinite loop because the right-hand side will evaluate negative for some values of the vertices. The area will always be positive, and therefore the function will evaluate to true going into a refinement iteration.

```
(*Extract vertices of region*)
verts = MeshCoordinates[reg]
(*Extract vertices of 1st triangle*)
verts3d1 = Most@verts
(*Evaluate mesh refinement function*)
0.025 (1 - 10 Norm[Mean[verts3d1]])
```

[image: Negative mesh refinement function]

Here's an example of a more well-behaved mesh refinement function in 2D.

```
verts2d1 = Most[verts /. {{x_, y_, z_} :> {x, y}}]
center2d1 = Mean[verts2d1]
DiscretizeRegion[Polygon[verts2d1], 
 MeshRefinementFunction -> 
  Function[{vertices, area}, 
   area > 0.000025 (1 + 100 Norm[Mean[vertices] - center2d1])]]
```

[image: 2D mesh refinement]

We consider the 1st triangle only, we can show that the improved mesh refinement function still fails. First, we will show that are simplified region succeeds again with `MaxCellMeasure`:

```
reg3d1 = MeshRegion[verts3d1, Polygon[{{1, 2, 3}}]];
HighlightMesh[
   DiscretizeRegion[reg3d1, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> #}], 
   1] & /@ {0.025, 0.0025}
```

[image: 1 triangle with Max cell measure]

Second, we will show that it fails with the improved `MeshRefinementFunction`.

```
center3d1 = Mean[verts3d1]; 
DiscretizeRegion[reg3d1, 
 MeshRefinementFunction -> 
  Function[{vertices, area}, 
   area > 0.000025 (1 + 100 Norm[Mean[vertices] - center3d1])]]
```

[image: Failing with mesh refinement function]

This result is similar to that obtained with the simple example in the OP.

Interestingly, there is a somewhat related recent question [Change mesh density of Graphics3D object made of Triangles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/238759). To me, this indicates that `DiscretizeRegion` may not be entirely robust when it comes to embedding 2D objects in 3D. Hopefully, someone can find a suitable workaround.