# Change mesh density of Graphics3D object made of Triangles

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, mesh

I am new to mesh discretisation on Mathematica. I have a `Graphics3D` object made up of `Triangle`s, that I would like to convert into a `MeshRegion` object using `DiscretizeGraphics` (see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeGraphics.html).

In particular, I would like to control the mesh density. The above link tells me to use the `MaxCellMeasure` option, but it doesn't seem to make any difference to my graphics!

Thus,

```
Table[DiscretizeGraphics[g, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> m}], {m, {0.3, 0.01, 0.001}}]
```

gives:
[image]

As you can see, the meshing is unchanged. It doesn't matter if I replace "Area" by "Volume" or "Length".

Can someone please tell me how to do this properly? Is this happening because my `Graphics` is already made up of triangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just learnt from this post ([Possible Bug in DiscretizeRegion with Option MaxCellMeasure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56613/possible-bug-in-discretizeregion-with-option-maxcellmeasure)) that this might be a bug in Mathematica.

Using one of the solutions recommended here, I applied `DiscretizeRegion` with the `MaxCellMeasure` option to the meshed object produced by `DiscretizeGraphics`:

```
mr = DiscretizeGraphics[g];
DiscretizeRegion[mr, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> #}] & /@ {0.1, 
  0.01, 0.005}
```

And this time, it works:
[image]

Should I report this bug to Mathematica? The previous bug, mentioned in the post, was solved several years ago.