# Using DiscretizeGraphics on a Graphics3D object that is produced by combining multiple Graphics3D objects

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, mesh

Consider the following two `Graphics3D` objects that can individually be meshed using `DiscretizeGraphics`. The first is a cone (produced via `ParametricPlot3D`):

```
centre = {-0.7187445069014783`, 0.9892669447371633`, 
   0.17750547233320435`};
tip = {0, 0, 0};
vec1 = {-0.6163296489428813`, 1.088347326141306`, 
   0.04000644601351258`};
vec2 = {-0.8446234808586002`, 0.9224821483732286`, 
   0.04000644601351257`};
{v1, v2, v3} = # & /@ HodgeDual[centre - tip];
e1 = Normalize[v1];
e3 = Normalize[centre - tip];
e2 = Cross[e1, e3];

coneBounded = 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  s*tip + (1 - s)*(centre + Rc*(Cos[t]*e1 + Sin[t]*e2)), {t, 0, 
   2 \[Pi]}, {s, 0, 1}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Mesh -> None, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 
    RegionMember[
     HalfSpace[Cross[vec1 - tip, vec2 - tip], tip], {x, y, z}]],
  PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"][1]];
DiscretizeGraphics[%];
{%%, %}
```

gives:

[image]

The second is a pair of triangles that bounds the cone:

```
t1={{0.0735871, 0.0450942, 0.0800129}, {0., 0., 0.}, {-0.61633, 1.08835, 
  0.0400064}};
t2={{0., 0., 0.}, {-0.0656268, -0.0560506, 
  0.0800129}, {-0.844623, 0.922482, 0.0400064}};
conetriangle = Graphics3D[{Blue, Triangle[t1], Triangle[t2]}]
DiscretizeGraphics[%];
DiscretizeRegion[%,  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.01}];
{%%%, %}
```

giving:

[image]

Note: The further use of `DiscretizeRegion` is required to counteract a bug reported here: [Change mesh density of Graphics3D object made of Triangles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238758/change-mesh-density-of-graphics3d-object-made-of-triangles/238759#238759)

I can also try and combine one cone and two adjoining triangles (using `Show`), and the result is as expected (the discretisation considers the combined object as a piecewise union and thus discretises separately):

```
Show[coneBounded, conetriangle] ;
DiscretizeGraphics[%];
DiscretizeRegion[%, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.01}];
{%%%, %}
```

giving:

[image]

**PROBLEM 1**:

How do I get such a combined `Graphics3D` object to mesh with a uniform `MaxCellMeasure` everywhere? Thus, in the above picture, the cone and triangles would have roughly the same cell size.

---

**PROBLEM 2**:

Another problem arises when I try to combine many such cones and triangles together (using a combination of `Table` with rotations, and then `Show`), and then use `DiscretizeGraphics` on the whole. Here, I only get the triangles back!

```
fullSolution;
DiscretizeGraphics[%];
{%%, %}
(*where do the cones go?*)
```

gives:

[image]

I have no idea what is going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the code for `coneBounded` and `conetriangle`?

Comment: @user21 Done. Sorry for that.

Comment: When I run your code, it still misses definitions. Anyways. have a look at the [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html). You might be able to do it with that.