# problem with DelaunayMesh 3D coordinates

Tags: finite-element-method, computational-geometry, mesh

I found `DelaunayMesh` works fine for 2D. For example,

```
coordinateList = Tuples[{Range[3], Range[3]}];
DelaunayMesh[coordinateList, PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

gives

[image: 2D Delaunay triangulation]

Oddly enough, it does not work for simple regular point array like below

```
coordinateList = Tuples[{Range[3], Range[3], Range[3]}];
DelaunayMesh[coordinateList, PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

which just prints out the original data like

```
DelaunayMesh[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 
   2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 1}, {1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 3}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 
   2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 
   2}, {2, 3, 3}, {3, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 
   2}, {3, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 3, 3}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

I have to jiggle each point a little to make `DelaunayMesh` work. Define

```
ClearAll[jiggleCoordinateList];
jiggleCoordinateList[coordinateList_, eta_] := Module[{},
  RandomReal[eta*{-1, 1}, Dimensions@coordinateList] + coordinateList
  ]
```

then

```
coordinateList = Tuples[{Range[3], Range[3], Range[3]}];
DelaunayMesh[jiggleCoordinateList[coordinateList, 0.00001], 
 PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

gives

[image: Delaunay tetrahedralization of "jiggled" grid]

But why is that? I can not think of a reason why a regular point array in 3D can not be `DelaunayMesh`ed.

Though a jiggled mesh is fine for display, for calculations, a jiggled mesh is not the same as the original mesh and will introduce error (even though it is small, it is not perfect).

Is there any workaround other than jiggling coordinates?

Comment: This looks like the situation where a Delaunay triangulation is not well-defined if concyclic points are present.

Comment: Hi, @J.M. more explanations? :)

Comment: It's when if you have a bunch of points that belong to one circle, then a Delaunay triangulation will (usually) have trouble. I am not sure, because I haven't done extensive experiments yet.

Comment: Hmm, what version are you using? `DelaunayMesh[Tuples[ConstantArray[Range[3], 3]]]` seems to work fine in 11.3 ...

Comment: @J.M. That is weird. I use 12.2

Comment: Seem to work in version 12.0, too. Please contact the support about this. This is quite certainly a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a workaround you can use the finite element mesh generator:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
coordinateList = Tuples[{Range[3], Range[3], Range[3]}];
MeshRegion[ToElementMesh[coordinateList], PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

[image]

Comment: That is quite ironic for me. Because I was reading doc and tutorial of `ToElementMesh` all day and never thought it could directly support bare coordinate list. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @matheorem, and that's a shortcoming; in the next version you can specify `ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coords]` and it will give you the Delaunay triangulation. If you have suggestions for improving the FEM documentation, let me know.

Comment: I do have other questions about FEM package. I will post later :)

Comment: Hi, user21. I am wondering if I could directly control the mesh quality during `ToElementMesh[coords]`. I mean throw away triangles whose quality is below a threshold, So I won't have to do a postprocessing deleting work. I tried various options of `ToElementMesh` all failed.

Comment: @matheorem, no that's not possible. The point of a Delaunay mesh is to connect a set of nodes, however,  it does not fiddle with the position of them.

Comment: Yeah, I know the definition of Delaunay mesh is to generate triangles to span the largest space. But for interpolation on machine precision point array, the mesh frequenlty got many bad triangles at edges. So before deleting those bad triangles, the mesh is not usable for interpolation.